# Notepad ++ Change last name from Upper case to Proper case

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

Hi I would like to replace all the "last name" instances in my text file from full upper case to Proper case. DOE to Doe or IPSUM to Ipsum as you can see below

```
Name = John DOE
Random info 1
Random info 2
RandomInfo

Name = Lorem IPSUM
Random info 1
Random info 2
RandomInfo
```

to

```
Name = John Doe
Random info 1
Random info 2
RandomInfo

Name = Lorem Ipsum
Random info 1
Random info 2
RandomInfo
```

And I would like to do that for thousands of instances like this in a text file. What do I have to "Find and replace" on Notepad++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:Name =|\G(?!^)) \K(\w)(\w+)`
- Replace with: `\u$1\L$2`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    Name =          # literally
  |               # OR
    \G(?!^)         # restart from last match position if not beginning of line
)               # end group
                # a space
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
(\w)            # group 1, first letter
(\w+)           # group 2, following letters
```

**Replacement:**

```
\u$1        # uppercased  1rst letter
\L$2        # lowercased ather letters
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Toto! Much appreciated. What if I want to replace Names that have hyphens. Let's say I want to make "John DOE-DOE" into "John Doe-Doe".

Comment: @sammodsJust change the space (before `\K`) into `[ -]`. the regex becomes: `(?:Name =|\G(?!^))[ -]\K(\w)(\w+)`

Comment: Just did, big big thanks @toto

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
by regular expression:

[image]

**Find** : `Name = (\w+) \<(\w+)`
**Replace** : `Name = \1 \L\u\2`

**Explanation:**

Find text

- `\<` matches the beginning of a word
- `(\w+)` matches any sequence of word letters

Replace text

- `\L` translates everything to lowercase until the end of the replacement string
- `\u` translates the next letter to uppercase
- `\1` places the first captured () search group
- `\2` places the second captured () search group

Comment: Thank you so much! Much appreciated. What if I want to replace Names that have hyphens. Let's say I want to make "John DOE-DOE" into "John Doe-Doe".

Comment: You may duplicate the last-name group twice: Find `Name = (\w+) \<(\w+)-\<(\w+)`, replace `Name = \1 \L\u\2-\L\u\3`.